# Getting content from xml

Tags: php, xml

I'm using this Iplocator to locate users countries

http://api.locatorhq.com/?user=Muhammad3241&key=c5018d1f3e2434e5277bc3143abbb41411f55834&ip=118.92.16.247&format=xml

how can I retrieve only  so that I can use it in php file.

many thanks,

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: You do realize you put your key in this posting ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SimpleXML_Load_String() to turn the XML into an object, and use PHP iterators to access the object.  This shows how it's done.

See http://www.laprbass.com/RAY_temp_atieh.php

```
<?php // RAY_temp_atieh.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// ACQUIRE AN OBJECT REPRESENTATION OF THE DATA
$url = 'http://api.locatorhq.com/?user=Muhammad3241&key=c5018d1f3e2434e5277bc3143abbb41411f55834&ip=118.92.16.247&format=xml';
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = simplexml_load_string($xml);

// ACTIVATE THIS TO SHOW THE WHOLE OBJECT
// var_dump($obj);

// ACQUIRE THE COUNTRY
$c = (string)$obj->countryName;

var_dump($c);
```

Comment: Thank you Ray,
but this is the result:
string(0) "" 
any suggestions?

Comment: On my server, where I tested this code before posting it, I see string(11) "New Zealand" -- did you make any changes to the code?  Or did something change in the response from the API?

Comment: I found that allow_url_fopen was turned off, I turn it on and everything worked fine!!
Thanks,

Comment: Great!  You can test the value of $obj and if it is FALSE you know something is amiss ;-)